# Using lists to find the number of times a character occurs

Tags: c

How do I make `letters()` find the times a character occurs in `name[]`?
When I call `report` (function that prints struct parts), I want to print something like that: Lets say `name` is `"hello"`, I want each element of my list to be something like that (`h:1` `e:1` `l:2` `o:1`); that's what `report` should print.(Still here)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
struct charact {  
    char ch;  
    int occurs;   
    struct charact *next; 
}; 
typedef struct charact Char; 
typedef Char * ListofChar; 
typedef Char * CharNode_ptr; 

void letters(  char name[50],     ListofChar * chars_ptr); 
void report( ListofChar chars ); 
Char * createnode( char ch ); 


int main() {  
    char name[50]; 
    ListofChar chars = NULL; 

    scanf("%s", name);   
    letters(name, &chars);  

    report(chars);  

    return 0; 
} 

Char * createnode( char ch ) { 
   CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;  
   newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char)); 
   newnode_ptr -> ch = ch; 
   newnode_ptr -> occurs = 0;   
   newnode_ptr -> next = NULL;    
   return newnode_ptr; 
} 
void letters(  char name[50],    ListofChar * lst_ptr) { 

return; 
}
```

Comment: Look at each element of the array in a loop and if that element matches the character that you are looking for, increment a counter.

Comment: You do so using a frequency array. To map frequency of occurrence of `A-Za-z0-9` you need an array of `62` elements initialized to all zero at the beginning. (using a second array containing the literal `ABCDEF....789` to map indexes, or use simple `if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')` to bracket and use an offset). Iterate over the characters in `name` and increments the element in your frequency array that corresponds to that char. At the end simply loop over your frequency array and output the results.

Comment: I mean you got two upvotes and one downvote and two people helping you in comments so I don't know what the problem is